# Unimodality of continuous univariate distributions

Tags: distributions, mode

What are the different methods to prove that a continuous univariate distribution is unimodal?

Some of them are available at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unimodality) but not much detail is given. Solution or suggestion of any continuous univariate distribution is welcome.

Comment: Are you asking about mathematical methods to show a known distribution is unimodal, or about tests for unimodality of a population given a sample?

Comment: @Scortchi mathematical method to show a known distribution is unimodel

Comment: Your question is unclear and kind of broad. It would help if you could be clearer about what you want. I'll assume for the moment that your question is at least limited to the continuous case; you use the same general methods to identify the number of modes as you would to count local and global maxima of functions, with the same caveats that apply there. As such this is primarily a mathematical question about functions, though with the additional restrictions that apply to densities.

Comment: @Glen_b: I think it is a useful question, see **Adam Bailey** answer and **Whuber** comments. The usual technique we used has many fault also there are some other method which is not known in statistician. So my attempt is to gather material on one page about unimodality. Yes it is limited to continuous univariate distribution if I generalize it then discrete and multivariate version also added. Which make it difficult to answer and may not understandable for common person.

Comment: @Whuber: I dont understand a question have 3 up vote and you put it on hold, In above **Glen_b** says question is not general and you are saying question is too broad. I am upset and dont understand, in my opinion it is a good question and to be answered.

Comment: @Glen_b and I agree it is too broad. I posted comments to the reply detailing how much would be required to address this question and I posted a comment asking the question to be changed to make it less general. A month has passed with no improvement, so I have voted to close it until (if) it can be refined.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the distribution is defined by a function $f(x)$.  The obvious method is to use calculus to find all local maxima of the function.  It has a local maxima at $x = x^*$ if $f'(x^*) = 0$ and $f''(x^*) < 0$, where $f'$ is the first derivative and $f''$ the second dervivative.  Having identified all values of $x$ corresponding to local maxima (often there will only be one), find the associated maximum values of $f$ and compare them.  If one of the local maxima is greater than any others, then the distribution is unimodal (although as the Wikipedia article notes the terminology is not always consistently used and a distribution with two local maxima, one greater than the other, is sometimes described as bimodal).

Note however that the above method will not work in a case where the function, though continuous, is not differentiable at all values of $x$.  An example is the [Laplace distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_distribution), which is not differentiable at its mode. In such a case it may be best just to calculate and plot the value of the function at regularly spaced values of $x$ to determine its approximate shape.

Comment: (1) When a function has more than one region of local maxima, it (by definition) is *multimodal.*  Thus, as soon as you can find two locations of a *strict* local maximum, the function is not unimodal. (2) It is important to check boundary values because they can be modes, too.  For instance, a Beta$(1/3, 1/3)$ distribution is bimodal but there are *no* points where $f'$ exists, equals zero, and $f''$ is negative. (3) What would you do when a distribution is not given by a PDF? *E.g.*, you have only its characteristic function, or perhaps it is defined as a function of other distributions.

Comment: (4) There exist infinitely differentiable PDFs that cannot be tested with your method: although they have multiple modes, they would not be detected because the second derivative is zero at all of them. Thus at best you propose a method of proving that something is *not* unimodal; it lacks the rigor needed to show that a distribution actually *is* unimodal.

Comment: @whuber Thank you, there is clearly more to this than I had realised.  Perhaps someone else can give a comprehensive answer.

Comment: I admire your optimism, Adam: you made a good effort at addressing a wide-open question. It would be more realistic to hope for answers that describe a few particular methods rather than something truly comprehensive. I, for one, would welcome changes to the question to bring it into sharper focus with a clear application.